Como extraer información de un campo de tipo json con Pyspark
Hola solicito su amable ayuda, la verdad soy novata manejando estructuras complejas :(
Tengo un json algo así
data = {
    "seccion": "Opcionales",
    "elementos": [
        {"personas": [2,3], "desc": "Amparada", "banAplicaTodos": False, "etiqueta": "Salud"},
        {"personas": [1, 2, 3], "desc": "Amparada", "banAplicaTodos": True, "etiqueta": "Extranjero"},
    ],
}

Y necesito extraer las "etiquetas" y "desc" que le corresponde a cada "persona", pero no se como, pienso que primero necesito obtener algo como esto
{2:{Salud:Amparada},3:{Salud:Amparada},1:{Extranjero:Amparada}2:{Extranjero:Amparada},3:{Extranjero:Amparada}}

Para posteriormente agrupar
{2:{Salud:Amparada,Extranjero:Amparada},3:{Salud:Amparada,Extranjero:Amparada},1:{Extranjero:Amparada}}

Para que se le pueda hacer un explode y me quede un dataframe así
|         persona|                            etiqueta|
|:---------------|:-----------------------------------|
|               1|{Extranjero:Amparada}               |
|               2|{Salud:Amparada,Extranjero:Amparada}|
|               3|{Salud:Amparada,Extranjero:Amparada}|

Les agradezco de antemano su tiempo.
